# Reason for different chemical shift in chiral solvents for enantiotopic protons

Tags: spectroscopy

The chemical shift of enantiotopic protons is defined as follows in [Spectroscopy/Homotopic, Enantiotopic, Diastereotopic](https://www.masterorganicchemistry.com/homotopic-enantiotopic-diastereotopic/)

> Enantiotopic protons have the same chemical shift in the vast majority of situations. However, if they are placed in a chiral environment (e.g. a chiral solvent) they will have different chemical shifts.

The second sentence in this question piques my interest. Even after some searching, I only saw this same sentence over and over again.

What makes the chiral solvent cause a change in magnetic environment causing the change in chemical shift for enantiotopic protons?

Comment: Generally, it can be assumed that the chiral solvent would interact with enantiotopic protons differently (because they are chiral). This would provide a different chemical environment for the enantiotopic protons. (The solvent need not stay bound to the solute, just the average interaction has to be different). Whether you see this difference in the actual spectrum is another matter entirely.